# Confluent-Kafka: Avro Serialization Confusions with Schema Handling in Python Consumers

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am try to understand Avro Serialization on Confluent Kafka along with Schema Registry usage. It was all going well till the end but the final expectations from AVRO made lots of Confusions to me. As per my reading and understanding, Avro Serialization gives us the flexibility that when we have a change in schema, we can simply manage that without impacting the older producer/consumer.

Following the same, I have developed a python producer which will Check for a Schema existence in Schema-Registry, if absent, create it and start Producing the json messages show below. When I need to change schema, I simply update it in my producer and this produces messages with new schema.

My Old Schema :

```
data = '{"schema":"{\\"type\\":\\"record\\",\\"name\\":\\"value\\",\\"namespace\\":\\"my.test\\",\\"fields\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"fname\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"lname\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"email\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"principal\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ipaddress\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"mobile\\",\\"type\\":\\"long\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"passport_make_date\\",\\"type\\":[\\"string\\",\\"null\\"],\\"logicalType\\":\\"timestamp\\",\\"default\\":\\"None\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"passport_expiry_date\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\",\\"logicalType\\":\\"date\\"}]}"}'
```

Sample Data from Producer-1 :

```
{u'mobile': 9819841242, u'lname': u'Rogers', u'passport_expiry_date': u'2026-05-21', u'passport_make_date': u'2016-05-21', u'fname': u'tom', u'ipaddress': u'208.103.236.60', u'email': u'tom_Rogers@TEST.co.nz', u'principal': u'tom@EXAMPLE.COM'}
```

My New Schema:

```
data = '{"schema":"{\\"type\\":\\"record\\",\\"name\\":\\"value\\",\\"namespace\\":\\"my.test\\",\\"fields\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"fname\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"lname\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"email\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"principal\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ipaddress\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"mobile\\",\\"type\\":\\"long\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"new_passport_make_date\\",\\"type\\":[\\"string\\",\\"null\\"],\\"logicalType\\":\\"timestamp\\",\\"default\\":\\"None\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"new_passport_expiry_date\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\",\\"logicalType\\":\\"date\\"}]}"}'
```

Sample Data from Producer-2 :

```
{u'mobile': 9800647004, u'new_passport_make_date': u'2011-05-22', u'lname': u'Reed', u'fname': u'Paul', u'new_passport_expiry_date': u'2021-05-22', u'ipaddress': u'134.124.7.28', u'email': u'Paul_Reed@nbc.com', u'principal': u'Paul@EXAMPLE.COM'}
```

Case 1: when I have 2 producers with above 2 schemas running together, I can successfully consume message with below code. All is well till here.

```
while True:
    try:
        msg = c.poll(10)

    except SerializerError as e:
        xxxxx 
        break
    print msg.value()
```

Case 2: When I go little deeper in JSON fields, things mixes up and breaks.

At first, say I have one producer running with ‘My Old Schema’ above and one consumer consuming these messages successfully.

```
print msg.value()["fname"] , msg.value()["lname"] , msg.value()["passport_make_date"], msg.value()["passport_expiry_date"]
```

When I run 2nd producer with ‘My New Schema’ mentioned above, my Old Consumers breaks as there is No Field passport_expiry_date and passport_make_date which is True.

Question:

Sometime I think, this is expected as it’s me(Developer) who is using the field names which are Not in the Message. But how Avro can help here? Shouldn't the missing field be handled by Avro? I saw examples in JAVA where this situation was handled properly but did not find any example in Python. For example, below github has perfect example of handling this scenario. When the field is not present, Consumer simply prints 'None'.

https://github.com/LearningJournal/ApacheKafkaTutorials

Case 3: When I run the combinations like Old Producer with Old Consumer and then in another terminals New Producer with New Consumer, Producers/Consumers mixes up and things break saying no json field.

Old Consumer ==>

```
print msg.value()["fname"] , msg.value()["lname"] , msg.value()["passport_make_date"], msg.value()["passport_expiry_date"]
```

New Consumer ==>

```
print msg.value()["fname"] , msg.value()["lname"] , msg.value()["new_passport_make_date"], msg.value()["new_passport_expiry_date"]
```

Question:

Again I think, this is expected. But, then Avro makes me think the right Consumer should get the right message with right schema. If I use msg.value() and always parse the fields at consumer side using programming without any role of Avro, then Where is the benefit of using avro? What is the benefit of sending schema with the messages/storing in SR?

Lastly, is there any way to check the schema attached to a message? I understand, in Avro, schema ID is attached with the message which is used further with Schema Registry while Reading and Writing messages. But I never see it with the messages.

Thanks much in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what compatibility setting you're using on the registry, but I will assume backwards, which means you would have needed to add a field with a default.

Sounds like you're getting a Python `KeyError` because those keys don't exist.

Instead of `msg.value()["non-existing-key"]`, you can try

option 1: treat it like a `dict()`

```
msg.value().get("non-existing-key", "Default value")
```

option 2: check individually for all the keys that might not be there

```
some_var = None  # What you want to parse
val = msg.value()
if "non-existing-key" not in val:
    some_var = "Default Value"
```

Otherwise, you must "project" the newer schema over the older data, which is what the Java code is doing by using a `SpecificRecord` subclass. That way, the older data would be parsed with the newer schema, which has the newer fields with their defaults.

If you used `GenericRecord` in Java instead, you would have similar problems. I'm not sure in Python there is an equivalent to Java's `SpecificRecord`.

By the way, I don't think the string `"None"` can be applied for a `logicalType=timestamp`

Comment: I had to use compatibility 'None' due to some BUG which was stopping me creating multiple Schema for an Object. Would anything change in that case?
The options you provided to handle Non existing-key are on programming basis which I wanted to avoid to see the AVRO Magic. In that case, Avro seems not much helpful with Python Consumers. But would still work best with Java Consumers as the messages have Schema bound with them. Is it?

Lastly, as the message is a dict we can know the keys in it. Apart from that is there any way to get the Schema/ID attached with the message?

Comment: Messages never have a schema within them when using Confluent serializer tools. The schema is only in the registry. And if you set schema to NONE, then you are potentially breaking unsuspecting consumers of your data when the values completely change entirely and downstream tools cannot parse that data. Python/Java/other doesn't matter. [Setting mutiple schemas is not a bug, it is a feature](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/). A dict has keys and values; I don't understand... Yes, you can get the schema ID if you consume raw bytes and get 4 bytes (index 1-5)